# Is there a legal limit to the number of people in a room during an interview?

Tags: interviewing, united-states, legal, harassment

This may be better asked in the legal area, but i was curious if anyone knew if there was a legal limit to the number of people interviewing a candidate at a time? I’m talking about panel style interviews, where it’s you and the interviewers in the room.

I’ve heard of job interviews where there are upwards of 5 interviewers and am just wondering, how can this be legal? It seems like it creates undue intimidation, and borders on harassment of the candidate?

Edit: FYI this is in the USA

Comment: I was interviewed by 7 people once in one room... Happens - deal with it... And yes got the job.

Comment: There's probably a legal "occupancy" limit, but this has nothing to do with how many people can simultaneously participate in an interview. Why would there be any legal statute for this?

Comment: You're concerned about them wasting your time. They're dedicating 10 (or whatever the number is) of their own resource's times to the interview. If anyone should be worried about time wasting, it's them. I would take this as a sign that they really care about the process, versus that they're trying to intimidate you.

Comment: Not that long ago a panel of four or five people was the *normal* interviewing technique.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't think that numbers are really relevant to this concern.

I can certainly take only one interviewer to intimidate and harass a candidate.  A panel of 10 interviewers could equally well be warm, supportive and welcoming and be a fantastic experience for the candidate.

Answer (score 7):

There may be legal limits on persons in a room for "safety" concerns.  There are almost certainly no limits based on interviewing.

Some jobs will require candidates to make presentations to a room full of others.  When applying for a job in academia for example, one would almost certainly be expected to do "job talks" that might include dozens of potential peers.

Answer (score 4):

No such law exists in any country I'm aware of, and I fail to see why it would be required.

> It seems like it creates undue intimidation, and borders on harassment of the candidate?

Not at all. I've sat in interviews with one person where I felt *way* more intimidated than with 3 or 4 people. The number of people there has little to no bearing on intimidation and harassment - this is all down to the mannerisms and style of the interviewer(s).

Comment: @Fattie I'd still say that's nothing to do with number though. 1 slavering male that stares at her chest throughout the entire interview and makes inappropriate comments would be way, way worse than 10 interviewers that conduct themselves appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Once I had an interview at Northern Telecom<sup>1</sup> in RTP with eleven engineers + the manager.
He wanted everyone on both of his teams to meet me and be able to ask questions.
I doubt it was illegal.

It bothered me because I'm an introvert... they were all nice though.

The plus side is that now when 4-6 people interview me it doesn't bother me.

---

<sup>1</sup> It went bankrupt so no harm naming names.